# Delete GridView Row in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a GridView and in each item of this grid I have a Button that I use to delete the row of these button. But it is not working.

```
private void grvOrders_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;                   

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
           grvOrders.Rows.Remove(sender);
        }
    }
```

anyone could help me?

Comment: try `grvOrders.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you can't remove the sender: it's not a `DataGridViewRow`. Instead, use `grvOrders.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);`.